# Docker build throws "react-scripts: not found" error

Tags: docker, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app and want to publish my project with Docker.
with `docker build . -t react-docker` command and I'm getting this error:

> /bin/sh: 1: react-scripts: not found error Command failed with exit
>   code 127.

I deleted `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again, but my problem was not solved!

Dockerfile:

```
# stage: 1 
FROM node:8 as react-build 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY . ./ 
RUN yarn 
RUN yarn build 
# stage: 2 — the production environment 
FROM nginx:alpine 
COPY — from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html 
EXPOSE 80 
CMD [“nginx”, “-g”, “daemon off;”]
```

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: May [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1155) helps you?

Comment: Did you confirm `react-scripts` is in package.json?

Comment: @Bless yes, "react-scripts": {"version": "2.1.3", ...

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file? (may not be related to this issue)

Comment: @Bless yes, .git
node_modules
build

Comment: Give this a try - delete `yarn.lock`, run `yarn` locally and then the docker build command.

Comment: @bless Again, got that error :( (react-strips not found)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187493/discussion-between-bless-and-banafshe-alipour).

Answer (score 3):

Are you working with volumes? With a normal installation, docker should have access to your resource. But I have seen on my coworker's machine there were some weird permission problems. So docker couldn't write when trying to `yarn install`. So no `node_modules` were created (just as you described in the discussion). Thus no `react-scripts`.

Solution: Grant others access to the location where you want to mount. Or don't use volumes.

Comment: Yes, when working with volumes, this doesn't work. I had my repository cloned in OneDrive, which is network storage, and it kept giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to make it a two step process, you could do everything within one `Dockerfile` and then remove the dependencies needed for the installation afterwards.

I wrote a tutorial on the setup a little while back. Although it's directly with an `alpine` base.

[**Deploying ReactJS With Docker**](https://medium.com/@codingwithmanny/deploying-reactjs-with-docker-ac16728c0896)

---

The Dockerfile I wrote was:

**NOTE:** you could replace npm with yarn

**File:** `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine

EXPOSE 80

ADD config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY . /var/www/localhost/htdocs

RUN apk add nginx && \
    mkdir /run/nginx && \
    apk add nodejs && \
    apk add npm && \
    cd /var/www/localhost/htdocs && \
    npm install && \
    npm run build && \
    apk del nodejs && \
    apk del npm && \
    mv /var/www/localhost/htdocs/build /var/www/localhost && \
    cd /var/www/localhost/htdocs && \
    rm -rf * && \
    mv /var/www/localhost/build /var/www/localhost/htdocs;

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "exec nginx -g 'daemon off;';"]

WORKDIR /var/www/localhost/htdocs
```

File used for nginx configuration

**File:** `default.conf`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        location / {
                root   /var/www/localhost/htdocs/build;
                # this will make so all routes will lead to      
                # index.html so that react handles the routes              
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        # You may need this to prevent return 404 recursion.
        location = /404.html {
                internal;
        }
}
```

Hope this helps as a possible alternative.